# Split all "/" and create a CSV off this arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I am trying to split the "/" delimiter off this array and make it create a EURUSD.csv itself.

I know i can do this to a single text "quote"

```
stringsd = "EUR/USD";
stringsd.split("/")
```

But, how do i make it split arrays and create a .csv file for each splited String?

Like :

```
SYMBOLS_ALL = ['EUR/USD', 'USD/JPY', 'GBP/USD', 'EUR/GBP', 'USD/CHF', 'AUD/NZD', \
'CAD/CHF', 'CHF/JPY', 'EUR/AUD', 'EUR/CAD', 'EUR/JPY', 'EUR/CHF', 'USD/CAD', \
'AUD/USD', 'GBP/JPY', 'AUD/CAD', 'AUD/CHF', 'AUD/JPY', 'EUR/NOK', 'EUR/NZD', \
'GBP/CAD', 'GBP/CHF', 'NZD/JPY', 'NZD/USD', 'USD/NOK', 'USD/SEK']
```

And, create a .csv file for each of the Strings

Thanks for your kind reply..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SYMBOLS_ALL = ['EUR/USD', 'USD/JPY', 'GBP/USD', 'EUR/GBP', 'USD/CHF', 'AUD/NZD', \
'CAD/CHF', 'CHF/JPY', 'EUR/AUD', 'EUR/CAD', 'EUR/JPY', 'EUR/CHF', 'USD/CAD', \
'AUD/USD', 'GBP/JPY', 'AUD/CAD', 'AUD/CHF', 'AUD/JPY', 'EUR/NOK', 'EUR/NZD', \
'GBP/CAD', 'GBP/CHF', 'NZD/JPY', 'NZD/USD', 'USD/NOK', 'USD/SEK']



for s in SYMBOLS_ALL:
    filename = s.replace("/","") + ".csv"
    open(filename, 'w')
```

dont know if this is what you are looking for

Comment: Wow!. Amazing...It worked like a charm..
And, Sorry for this question also... I don't want this to slow down the python request to get some datas online.. How can i make it just walkover this without 2 milliseconds delay?
Thanks for your help

Comment: @ThisDude sorry i am not that familiar with python to answer such a performance question :\ but i think this could be a hard problem to solve

Comment: I think i figure out what to do... I'm looking at a option to just check if the first file exists...

Answer (score 0):

You should use built in Python [CSV](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) module.

```
import csv

SYMBOLS_ALL = ['EUR/USD', 'USD/JPY', 'GBP/USD', 'EUR/GBP', 'USD/CHF', 'AUD/NZD', \
'CAD/CHF', 'CHF/JPY', 'EUR/AUD', 'EUR/CAD', 'EUR/JPY', 'EUR/CHF', 'USD/CAD', \
'AUD/USD', 'GBP/JPY', 'AUD/CAD', 'AUD/CHF', 'AUD/JPY', 'EUR/NOK', 'EUR/NZD', \
'GBP/CAD', 'GBP/CHF', 'NZD/JPY', 'NZD/USD', 'USD/NOK', 'USD/SEK']


for currency in SYMBOLS_ALL:
    (first, second) = currency.split("/")
    for word in (first, second):
        with open('test{0}.csv'.format(str(word)), 'w') as fp:
            a = csv.writer(fp)
            data = [first,]
            a.writerow(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind and quick reply, where do you get "currency" from?
I'm new to python... Or, is that just meant to be there?

Comment: @ThisDude Currency is variable to hold every string from your SYMBOLS_ALL list while looping through it. First one will be 'EUR/USD' and so on...